# if charAt equal to a list of characters

Tags: javascript, charat

I want something like the following in Javascript

if str.charAt(index) (is in the set of) {".", ",", "#", "$", ";", ":"}

Yes, I know this must be simple, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. What I have now is

```
theChar = str.charAt(i);
if ((theChar === '.') || (theChar === ',') || (theChar === ... )) {
  // do stuff
}
```

This works, but there must be a better way.

Edit: I did this, but not sure if it's GOOD or not:

```
var punc = {
    ".":true,
    ",":true,
    ";":true,
    ":":true
};

if (punc[str.charAt[index]) { ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define an array with those chars and simply search in the array. One way to do that is the following:

```
var charsToSearch = [".", ",", "#", "$", ";", ":"];
var theChar = str.charAt(i); /* Wherever str and i comes from */

if (charsToSearch.indexOf(theChar) != -1) {
    /* Code here, the char has been found. */
}
```

Comment: @L105 are you sure about that?

Comment: Going to make a jsPerf.

Comment: While you're at it, make one using `String.indexOf` as well, e.g. `".,#$;:".indexOf(theChar) !== -1`. Although I don't think performance will matter much for this snippet.

Comment: [In my test](http://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-regex-m5) the String `indexOf` is fastest in Firefox, followed by the regex and then the array. It's the opposite in Chrome.

Comment: In my test, regex is 59% slower in chrome. http://jsperf.com/regexndexof, second time : 9% slower.

Comment: All of these work, but I am actaully sticking with the solution I came up with for this instance just because I really like the syntax `if (punc[str.charAt[index]) { ... }` even though it's a bit wordy in creating the set in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a regular expression:

```
var theChar = str.charAt(i);
if (/[.,#$;:]/.test(theChar)) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Not very friendly for new JavaScript programmers, but I guess it's good to demonstrate a *practical* solution.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens I guess it depends on where the new JavaScript programmer comes from :)  By the time I learned JavaScript, I'd known about regular expressions for a long time.

Comment: ah, that's what I was trying to do, but ten I got distracted by sets.